# Sorting array by property value bug

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array in a decending fashion by the property commonVotes. Sorting is going somewhat well except the last element (Pride) after being sorted isn't going in the correct place.

Array before sorting:

```
[
    {
        "uuid": "4bf84d40-476e-11ea-87f1-f1c0fe90cd16",
        "name": "Pride",
        "createdAt": "2020-02-04T16:49:23.475Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-02-04T16:49:23.475Z",
        "commonVotes": 70,
        "deadlyVotes": 76
    },
    {
        "uuid": "4bf84d41-476e-11ea-87f1-f1c0fe90cd16",
        "name": "Lust",
        "createdAt": "2020-02-04T16:49:23.475Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-02-04T16:49:23.475Z",
        "commonVotes": 17,
        "deadlyVotes": 105
    },
    {
        "uuid": "4bf84d42-476e-11ea-87f1-f1c0fe90cd16",
        "name": "Glutony",
        "createdAt": "2020-02-04T16:49:23.475Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-02-04T16:49:23.475Z",
        "commonVotes": 40,
        "deadlyVotes": 21
    },
    {
        "uuid": "4bf84d43-476e-11ea-87f1-f1c0fe90cd16",
        "name": "Envy",
        "createdAt": "2020-02-04T16:49:23.475Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-02-04T16:49:23.475Z",
        "commonVotes": 82,
        "deadlyVotes": 75
    }
]
```

Array after sorting:

```
[
    {
        "uuid": "4bf84d43-476e-11ea-87f1-f1c0fe90cd16",
        "name": "Envy",
        "createdAt": "2020-02-04T16:49:23.475Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-02-04T16:49:23.475Z",
        "commonVotes": 82,
        "deadlyVotes": 75
    },
    {
        "uuid": "4bf84d42-476e-11ea-87f1-f1c0fe90cd16",
        "name": "Glutony",
        "createdAt": "2020-02-04T16:49:23.475Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-02-04T16:49:23.475Z",
        "commonVotes": 40,
        "deadlyVotes": 21
    },
    {
        "uuid": "4bf84d41-476e-11ea-87f1-f1c0fe90cd16",
        "name": "Lust",
        "createdAt": "2020-02-04T16:49:23.475Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-02-04T16:49:23.475Z",
        "commonVotes": 17,
        "deadlyVotes": 105
    },
    {
        "uuid": "4bf84d40-476e-11ea-87f1-f1c0fe90cd16",
        "name": "Pride",
        "createdAt": "2020-02-04T16:49:23.475Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-02-04T16:49:23.475Z",
        "commonVotes": 70,
        "deadlyVotes": 76
    }
]
```

Sorting code:

```
sins.sort((a, b) => {
  return (a.commonVotes > b.commonVotes) ? 1 : -1
})
```

How do I fix this? Is it a bug placed by the Illuminati that is forver bugged?

Comment: That's not what your code does when I run it. It yields an ordering 17, 30, 70, 82. https://jsbin.com/fayalexaxu/edit?js,console

Comment: btw, you are also not taking into account when a.commonVotes equals b.commonVotes, although that would not affect your sample data.

Comment: Looks like whatever your problem is, you inadvertently fixed it in the process of typing up your question -- compare to your original code to find your answer.

Comment: maybe you have a look to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785/sorting-in-javascript-shouldnt-returning-a-boolean-be-enough-for-a-comparison

Answer (score 0):

Try asc

```
sins.sort((x, y) => {
  return (x.commonVotes < y.commonVotes) ? -1 : (x.commonVotes > y.commonVotes) ? 1 : 0
})
```

Try desc

```
sins.sort((x, y) => {
  return (x.commonVotes < y.commonVotes) ? 1 : (x.commonVotes > y.commonVotes) ? -1 : 0
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be working fine.

```
a.sort((a, b) => (a.commonVotes > b.commonVotes) ? 1 : -1);
```